# The ends of a group

Tags: geometric-group-theory

May I refer you to theorem $8.32$ on page $146$ in [Metric Spaces of Non-Positive Curvature](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=M7XrCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=ends+theorem+0+1+or+2+Arzela+Ascoli&source=bl&ots=l1MpNwdA9W&sig=GS8Ei5Xw3_aD4YDakaR6SW75oi0&hl=es-419&sa=X&ei=ah1ZVZ6eH9GVyATT5oHwCw&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=ends%20theorem%200%201%20or%202%20Arzela%20Ascoli&f=false)

In the last paragraph, why is it the case that $H$ has finite index implies there is a constant $\mu$ such that every vertex of the Cayley graph lies in a $\mu$-neighborhood of $H$?

Comment: Did you read the previous couple sections on quasi-isometries? Consider the natural action of a finite index subgroup on a cayley graph of the full group...(apply some theorems from that section here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be the group that contains $H$ with finite index. By definition of finite index, there exists a finite subset $\{g_1,…,g_K\}$ of $G$ such that 
$$G = H g_1 \cup H g_2 \cup \cdots \cup H g_K
$$
Given any $g \in G$, there exists $h \in H$ and $k \in \{1,…,K\}$ such that $g = h g_k$, so $d(g,h) = d(h^{-1} g,\text{Id}) = d(g_k,\text{Id})$, and therefore 
$$d(g,H) \le \mu = \text{Max}_{k=1}^K d(g_k,\text{Id})
$$